# Distribution for eldery people

Tags: distribution-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What linux is best suited for people new to computers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/what-linux-is-best-suited-for-people-new-to-computers)

My grandparents would like to use a computer. They have already used a Windows Vista machine but so little and with such difficulty that I would like to install an easy to use distribution for them.

They will basically be browsing the internet, sending mails and watching photos(from a photo camera)

Do we have any free distribution that meets their needs?